# Sentence structure "the same ~as~"

Tags: sentence-construction, as

Here's an original sentence.

> 1. When you're in emotional pain, treat yourself with the same compassion you would expect from a truly good friend.

And here are sentences that I've made to compare and hence understand fully.

> 2. When you're in emotional pain, treat yourself with the same compassion as the one you would expect from a truly good friend.

I'm a English learner and I'm not sure why, but I always expect an "as" after "the same + noun". So, for me, sentence #2 is much more comfortable to read and speak.

Are #1 and #2 interchangeable or do they mean different things?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea. They would mean the same thing, except that #2 is incorrect. Although I can see what you were thinking, and you are very close.

You are correct that usually we have "as" after "the same + noun". However, you can leave off "as" and it will be implied.

> "This is the same guitar [as] Eddie van Halen used!"

Another thing that is left out of this sentence but still implied is "The guitar that". So the **FULL** sentence is

> "This is the same guitar *as* **the guitar that** Eddie van Halen used!"

However, it is still valid if you leave out "The guitar that".

Let's take "treat yourself with the same compassion".

"treat yourself with the same compassion" -- "as What?" The answer is "[The compassion] you would expect from a truly good friend."

The only problem with your sentence, is that you refer to "The compassion you would except from a truly good friend." as "the **ONE** you would expect..." You cannot count compassion. So you should not refer to it as "one".